# Max data http_build_query() can handle

Tags: php, curl

I have a huge multidimensional array and I am trying to convert it to a query string with `http_build_query($data)` and post it via `cURL`. But this function does not convert all of my data to a query string.

For example I have an array which has **100** arrays. It almost converts **80** arrays to query string but not the rest of the arrays.

If someone knows the max length/size of characters/data that this function can handle and any solution to this.

Comment: send that huge array as json string

Comment: yes it is a solution but I need to know why http_build_query() is not letting me ?

Comment: Browsers also have a limit of URL-size. I think it is max 2k or 4k. If you need to send large data, use the POST method.